# How to performantly record datetimes for analysis purposes?

Tags: mysql, date

In order to analyze dates and times I am creating a MySQL table where I want to keep the time information. Some example analyses will be stuff like:

- Items per day/week/month/year
- Items per weekday
- Items per hour
- etc.

Now in regards to performance, what way should I record in my datatable:

1. date type: Unix timestamp?
2. date type: datetime?
3. or keep date information in one row each, e.g. `year`, `month`, `day` in separate fields?

The last one, for example, would be handy if I'm analysing by weekday; I wouldn't have to perform `WEEKDAY(item.date)` on MySQL but could simply use `WHERE item.weekday = :w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your usage, you want to use the native `datetime` format.  Unix formats are most useful when the major operations are (1) ordering; (2) taking differences in seconds/minutes/hours/days; and (3) adding seconds/minutes/hours/days.  They need to be converted to internal date time formats to get the month or week day, for instance.

You also have a potential indexing issue.  If you want to select ranges of days, hours, months and so on for your results, then you want an index on the column.  For this purpose an index on a `datetime` is *probably* sufficient.

If the summaries are by hour, you might find it helpful to stored the date component in a date field and the hour in a separate column.  That would be particularly helpful if you are combining hours from different days.

Whether you break out other components of the date, such as weekday and month, for indexing purposes would depend on the volume of data in the table, performance requirements, and the queries you are planning on running.  I would not be inclined to do this, except as a later optimization.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is: store things as they should be stored, don't do performance tweaks until you're hitting the bottleneck. If you store your date as separate fields, you'll eventually stumble upon a situation you need this date as a whole inside your database (e.g. update query for a particular range of time), and this will be like hell - condition `from 3 april 2015 till 15 may 2015` would be as giant as possible.

You should keep your dates as date type. This will grant you maximum flexibility, (most probably) query readability and will keep all of your opportunities to work with them. The only thing I really can recommend is storing the same date divided into year/month/day in next columns - of course, this will bloat your database and require extreme caution on update scenarios, but this will allow you to use any variant of source data in your queries.